# Unable to start kurento media server with docker

Tags: docker, kurento

I'm trying to run kurent-media-server, by following the instructions found here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/kurento/kurento-media-server

I've followed them, but I am still unable to connect to the server.

After running

```
$ docker run --name kms -d -p 8888:8888 \
    kurento/kurento-media-server
```

```
$ curl -i -N \
    -H "Connection: Upgrade" \
    -H "Upgrade: websocket" \
    -H "Host: 127.0.0.1:8888" \
    -H "Origin: 127.0.0.1" \
    http://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
```

I get `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`, instead of

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: WebSocket++/0.7.0
```

How can I fix this? I seem to have done done everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using latest image of `kurento-media-server` docker. I am using version `6.13.2` and it works fine for me.